# Formik, useField() in child component?

Tags: javascript, formik

I have a separate module that I'm working on, this module is meant to contain formik supporting HTML input elements.

The issue is I'm unable to use the `useFields()` hook since my module component doesn't connect to the formik context.

Here's my component that resides in a different module:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { useField } from "formik";

export function TextField({ label, ...props }) {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  return <input {...field} {...meta} />;
}

TextField.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  showErrors: PropTypes.bool
};

TextField.defaultProps = {
  label: "",
  showErrors: true
};

export default TextField;
```

and here is my Formik form:

```
<Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstName: "firstName"
      }}
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }, 1000);
      }}
    >
      {formik => (
        <Form>
          <TextField name="firstName" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
```

No matter what I do I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFieldProps' of undefined

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please make sure you didn't use TextField some other place, not under Formik context.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the useField docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/useField) I would expect:

```
<input {...field} {...props} />
```

The input component does not expect the {...meta} props.

other than that I could not reproduce your error.